Iteratively finding matrix inverse from a given inverted matrix.
Let's say I need to find inverse of a bunch of matrices $A_0, A_1, ... A_n$.
As the matrices are large (in my use-case), I am iteratively finding the inverse of each matrix $A_i$ using Newton matrix inverse: $$X^{t+1} = X^{t} (2I -AX^t)$$
Assuming the original matrices $A_i$ is close to $A_{i+1}$ with some margin $\epsilon$: $$||A_{i+1} - A_{i}||_2^2 < \epsilon$$ and we have already computed the inverse of $A_{i}$ which lets say is $B_i = A_i^{-1}$.
Is there a way to find the inverse of $A_{i+1}$ using Newton's iteration but with the initialization of $B_i$ (or some transformation of this).

just use $B_i$ as the starting point $X^0$

It didnot work out for me. Should it provably work?

No, but if it doesn't work, then probably nothing else does, not without some additional structure at least

Just out of curiosity, do you absolutely need the entire inverse matrix? There are far more efficient methods available if you only need, say, to solve a linear system or obtain specific elements of the inverse

yes, indeed. those are the block covariance matrices in my case..

Has the question been resolved?

@CarlChristian as MP-inverse is not continuous, we cannot guarantee the convergence.

I have demonstrated that $A_{i+1}$ can be very close to $A_i$ while $A_{i+1}^{-1}$ is very far from $B_i = A_{i}^{-1}$. In my mind, that is an acceptable answer and I cannot improve my answer without additional comments from you. There is no way that to find a transformation of $B_i$ that will deliver a good approximation of $B_{i+1}$, unless you provide additional information about your problem, i.e., describe the underlying application in some detail. It is of course too late to do that now, but you can always write new question with more details and link to this question.

Oh my bad, I thought someone else asked this question. But I would say that I have found an explicit formulation in terms of the difference. See Problem 77 Chapter 6 of this book: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b97366.

If $A$ is a good approximation of $B$, then $A^{-1}$ is not necessarily a good approximation of $B^{-1}$.
As an example consider the case of $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 10^{-9} \end{bmatrix} $$ and $$B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 10^{-3} \end{bmatrix}.$$
It is clear that $A$ and $B$ are both nonsingular and
$$\frac{\|B-A\|_2}{\|B\|_2} = 10^{-3} - 10^{-9}, \quad \frac{\|B^{-1} - A^{-1} \|_2}{\|B^{-1}\|_2}= \frac{10^9 - 10^3}{10^3} = 10^6 - 1.$$
We observe that while $A$ is a fair approximation of $B$, we cannot regard $A^{-1}$ as anything but a terrible approximation of $B^{-1}$.
We need more information about the nature of your matrices $A_i$ before any strategy can be suggested. Newton's method for the inverse of the matrix $A$ takes the form $$X_{k+1} = X_k + X_k(I - AX_k).$$ The residual $R_k$ given by $$R_k = I - AX_k$$ satisfies $$R_{k+1} = R_k^2$$ so it is clear that Newton's method will converge quadratically, provided that $\|R_0\|<1$. This condition is hard to satisfy in practice.

Regarding the nature of matrix A, they are symmetric and invertible. And yes I get your point, in my numerical approach, sometimes they do converge, but sometimes they don't.

@SatyaPrakashDash The condition of symmetry is not enough to improve matters. Sometimes the underlying application will infuse the matrices with useful properties that can be utilized.

Invertible implies a solution exists (not always known in advance when applying Newton) and symmetry at least reduces poor conditioning to the eigenvalues, so more preconditioners could be used
